# Receive hierarchy using Dictionary<string, dynamic> item

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary

I need to process an array of objects, which is containing a complete hierarchy. Like Country (USA) > State (Texas) > County (Harris) > City > Street (with lots of properties).

I have used a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` but I am unable to process the sub objects of any main objects. So following the example above the `Country` just processed fine, but I don't have any idea how to get the `States` inside the `Country` object.

I would like to process the following JSON:

```
{
  "Country": [
    {
      "Property1": "",
      "Property2": "",
      "Property3": "",
      "Property4": "",
      "Property5": "",
      "States": [
        { "Prop1": "", "Prop2": "", "Prop3": "", "Prop4": "" },
        { "Prop1": "", "Prop2": "", "Prop3": "", "Prop4": "" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Property1": "",
      "Property2": "",
      "Property3": "",
      "Property4": "",
      "Property5": "",
      "States": [
        { "Prop1": "", "Prop2": "", "Prop3": "", "Prop4": "" },
        { "Prop1": "", "Prop2": "", "Prop3": "", "Prop4": "" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the following controller method signature:

```
public ActionResult UploadApplication(List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> Country)
```

All the `Country` properties are populating just fine, but when I want to access the `States` it's say an object and there is no way to cast that into another `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: I have the following controller method signature:
public ActionResult UploadApplication(List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> Country)

All the Country properties are populating just fine, but when I want to access the "States" it's say an object and there is no way to cast that into another Dictionary<string, dynamic>

Comment: Please edit your question to include **all** required information. Don't put code in comments. Questions on SO should be self-contained.

Comment: I was able to edit the post, sorry, I'm not using stackoverflow to often. :)

Comment: Are you using [tag:asp.net-mvc]?  If so, please tag your question as such.  Also, which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MVC 4 ASP.NET, there is any difference between versions about JSON Parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `State` does not have a fixed structure (that `dynamic` in the Dictionary makes me think about that), you can write your code like this:

```
    public class Container
    {
        public List<Country> Country { get; set; }
    }
    public class Country
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
        public string Property4 { get; set; }
        public string Property5 { get; set; }

        public List<dynamic> States { get; set; }
    }

    //public class State
    //{
    //    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    //    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    //    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    //    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    //}

var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(@"
{
  ""Country"": [
    {
      ""Property1"": ""p1"",
      ""Property2"": ""p2"",
      ""Property3"": ""p3"",
      ""Property4"": ""p4"",
      ""Property5"": ""p5"",
      ""States"": [
        { ""Prop1"": ""p11"", ""Prop2"": ""p12"", ""Prop3"": ""p13"", ""Prop4"": ""p14"" },
        { ""Prop1"": ""p21"", ""Prop2"": ""p22"", ""Prop3"": ""p23"", ""Prop4"": ""p24"", ""Prop5"": ""p25"" }
      ]
    },
    {
      ""Property1"": """",
      ""Property2"": """",
      ""Property3"": """",
      ""Property4"": """",
      ""Property5"": """",
      ""States"": [
        { ""Prop1"": """", ""Prop2"": """", ""Prop3"": """", ""Prop4"": """" },
        { ""Prop1"": """", ""Prop2"": """", ""Prop3"": """", ""Prop4"": """" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
                ");
```

Your `States` list will contain dynamic objects with the provided properties.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static contract for your JSON structure:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Country> Country { get; set; }
}
public class Country
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    public string Property5 { get; set; }

    public List<State> States { get; set; }
}
public class State
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can parse the JSON string like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RootObject obj = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);

// example access
Console.WriteLine(obj.Country[0].States[0].Prop1);
```